# android missing in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

i just updated eclipse using Help > Check for Updates, but after i restarted eclipse, everything Android related in it just went missing, i can't create an Android project, can't find my AVD manager, etc. i tried reinstalling the ADT plugin using Help > install new software, but it says that the ADT was already installed.

i'm lost here, anybody can help? thank you so much

Comment: did you follow all the steps that are given in the documentation? I hope you do not have two separate installations of Eclipse?

Comment: yes, i did follow the steps in developer.android.com, but now that i checked it, i can't find anything related to android in the features and plugins folder under eclipse. but when i try to reinstall the plugin it says 'already installed'

Comment: finally used the classic solution, removed eclipse and download the latest version. fixed the problem.

Comment: I've just had this issue on : Version: Indigo Service Release 2
Build id: 20120216-1857

Answer (score 2):

For me it was that registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\1.6 was missing.  In order to get the Oracle 1.6 installer to run, I'd purged a few too many "1.6" registry keys.  Symptom: running "java" from a command window complained about a missing JRE DLL.

I think Eclipse somehow reverted to JDK 1.4 which I had in PATH.  I manually restored the registry key, logged out and into Windows, and ADK options reappeared in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Issue on Juno today. Searched for hours for a solution to what I assumed would be a common bug none found.

Like you I reinstalled Eclipse

I would just like to provide an additional detail which could help.

I extracted the new downloaded Eclipse version on top of the old. I replaced (yes to all) files with the same name. Doing it like this I preserved all my plugins and environment and it was no problem getting working again no damage.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 7 there seems to be some sort of permission issue (and opening Eclipse with Admin privileges doesn't help).  Open the SDK MAnager  (Windows Start->All Programs->Android SDK Tools->SDK Manager) with Admin permissions, and install any dependencies that aren't installed.  Then restart Eclipse